# How to pass an imported component through props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Is there a way I can pass a component through props to a child component from the parent without having to import it from the child?

**Parent component**:

```html
<template>
  <ChildComponent :component="componentName">
</template>
<script>
  import componentName from '@/components/componentName.vue'
</script>
```

**Child component**:

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <component :is="component">
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  props: {
    component: Object
  }
</script>
```

Currently, in this setup, I am getting *Unknown custom event  Did you register the component correctly?* Error. I know it wants me to register the component in the child component but I don't want to have to import the component from the child. Is there a way to pass the import to the child through props? Is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close, the issue is in your first template:

```html
<template>
  <ChildComponent :component="componentName">
</template>
<script>
  // this is not available in template scope
  import componentName from '@/components/componentName.vue'

  export default {
    data: {
      // this, however, is available!
      componentName
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes perfect sense. That was a no brainer after thinking about it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are mising `export default`.

`parent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent :component="componentName">
</template>
<script>
  import componentName from '@/components/componentName.vue'

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        componentName
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

`child.vue`:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <component :is="component">
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    component: Object
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have an issue your code, data should either be a function that `return` an Object, or ar object. But it cannot be a mix of both! And I don't really see how your answer differs from mine :/